# With the Azure ServiceBus 7.0 SDK, how do I get a reference to a ServiceBusClient using a ServiceBusManagementClient class?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-sdk-python

I'm using the latest Python Azure SDK

```
azure-mgmt-servicebus==6.0.0
azure-servicebus==7.0.0
```

I get a reference to a ServiceBusManagementClient like so ...

```
def _get_sb_client(self):
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(
       tenant_id=self._tenant,
        client_id=self._client_id,
        client_secret=self._client_secret
    )

    return ServiceBusManagementClient(
        credential, self._subscription)
```

However, according to this -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/servicebus?view=azure-python#service-bus-topics-and-subscriptions, in order to send a message on a topic,

```
topic_client = sb_client.get_topic("MyTopic")
```

I need a reference to a azure.servicebus.ServiceBusClient object.  However, the docs don't give any explanations about how to generate such an instance, other than through a connection string, which we are not using.  How can I get an instance of ServiceBusClient using ClientSecretCredential or ServiceBusManagementClient instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd respond with few things, do let me know if any of this needs clarification or is off-base:

1. The doc you linked is not for 7.0.0, but for 0.50.3, which might explain some of the confusion.  I would advise using the docs rooted in the [readme](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/README.md) for which one of the comparable docs to the one you referenced is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions).  (The process of replacing the historical docs is a known issue and being addressed, full disclosure speaking as a maintainer of the python SDK component)
2. I would call out that you initialized a ServiceBusManagementClient (which would be used for creating/deleting topics) and not the ServiceBusClient (which would be used for sending and receiving.)  kindly see the document I listed [above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) for an example of how to send to the topic.  I'll paste a comprehensive example from that link at the bottom of this post for posterity in case anything shifts in the future, that this post is still relevant for version 7.0.0
3. For authenticating using an Azure Identity credential, I would point you at the documentation in the readme [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus#create-client-using-the-azure-identity-library) and the [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/client_identity_authentication.py) linked therein, and pasted below.

**Example of sending and receiving to a topic/subscription**

```py
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

CONNECTION_STR = "<NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING>"
TOPIC_NAME = "<TOPIC NAME>"
SUBSCRIPTION_NAME = "<SUBSCRIPTION NAME>"

def send_single_message(sender):
    message = ServiceBusMessage("Single Message")
    sender.send_messages(message)
    print("Sent a single message")

def send_a_list_of_messages(sender):
    messages = [ServiceBusMessage("Message in list") for _ in range(5)]
    sender.send_messages(messages)
    print("Sent a list of 5 messages")

def send_batch_message(sender):
    batch_message = sender.create_message_batch()
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            batch_message.add_message(ServiceBusMessage("Message inside a ServiceBusMessageBatch"))
        except ValueError:
            # ServiceBusMessageBatch object reaches max_size.
            # New ServiceBusMessageBatch object can be created here to send more data.
            break
    sender.send_messages(batch_message)
    print("Sent a batch of 10 messages")

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)

with servicebus_client:
    sender = servicebus_client.get_topic_sender(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME)
    with sender:
        send_single_message(sender)
        send_a_list_of_messages(sender)
        send_batch_message(sender)

print("Done sending messages")
print("-----------------------")

with servicebus_client:
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME, subscription_name=SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, max_wait_time=5)
    with receiver:
        for msg in receiver:
            print("Received: " + str(msg))
            receiver.complete_message(msg)
```

**Example of authenticating with Azure Identity**

```py
import os
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
from azure.identity import EnvironmentCredential

FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAMESPACE = os.environ['SERVICE_BUS_NAMESPACE']
QUEUE_NAME = os.environ["SERVICE_BUS_QUEUE_NAME"]

credential = EnvironmentCredential()

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient(FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAMESPACE, credential)
with servicebus_client:
    sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    with sender:
        sender.send_messages(ServiceBusMessage('Single Message'))
```

Comment: In your second example, the one with "credential" and fully_qualified_namespace, you don't provide any information to the EnvironmentCrednetial object.  Before I used a ServiceBusService which took a namespace, shared_access_key_name, and shared_access_key_value.  Where do those fit in with the new paradigm?

Comment: So the EnvironmentCredential is a little special in that it tries to find the bits it needs from Environment Variables, see the doc [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-python).  

Now, when you say 'shared access key name' you're saying something very distinct from the question you asked initially, which had Service Principle credentials (which EnvironmentCredential supports).

With that said, If you do need SAS based auth, you'll want to leverage the connection string and the `from_connection_string` method.